# Using of if else statement

Tags: android

I'm working on an activity project which has three activity.I want to use a if else condition to go to `2nd or 3rd activity` but don't know how to use it in android.here's my code

MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText etOp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "-----------OnCreate--------------");
    etOp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);

}



public void Submit(View v) {
    String OpStr = etOp.getText().toString();
    double etInput = Double.parseDouble(OpStr);
    int etOp = 11;




    if (etOp == 11) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: what is `submit()` method??? have you defined it in layout for `onClick` attribute of `button`

Comment: yes I defined it in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You in the right direction:

```
Intent intent;
if (etOp == 11) {
  intent   = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
}
else {
    intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.But,the else statement isn't working,it always going to 2nd activity

Comment: well, since etOp ==11 so it always will go to the seconds Activity, don't you agree? if you want something else you have to change the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly call the submit method ..................
then the other activity is called automatically....

like that ......

```
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnId);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            submit();
        }
  });
```